# How to delete corrupted directory

Tags: rm, inode

While copying music to the sd card of my android phone, the laptop froze so I had to reboot it using *sysrq magic*. Now any file manager on my Ubuntu or Android shows a directory 0 bytes big, and undeletable. It's type is `inode/x-corrupted` The `ls` command ran from root user on Android, doesn't show the directory, however. The Internets tell me that I have to find out the *inode* of the directory, but when I do `ls -i` from my Ubuntu, it shows every others directory inode, and an I/O error on this one.
What do I do to get rid of it?

Comment: Have you tried fscking it?

Comment: @PSkocik I dunno how. fsck doesn't like it, I googled it and I dunno what to install to use `fsck.ntfs`. I have Ubuntu and I've searched *ntfs* and *fsck* in Synaptic, nothing useful came up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue with my SD card recently. I was not able to fix it under Linux. However, as soon as I plugged the card into a Windows machine, the system came up with a message asking whether I want to repair the card as apparently it was not unmounted correctly. The repair under Windows helped.

Answer (score 0):

how about running a file system check on the SD card?  insert the card and under linux run

```
fsck /dev/mmcblk01p1
```

for example. If you're note sure what's the name of the device name given, just see dmesg upon inserting the card. Aaand do not forget to umount it prior fsck